# GFG Parenthesis Checker problem in C++ giving wrong answer

Tags: c++, stack

GFG Parenthesis Checker showing wrong answer at test case "[][]" but when i go with custom test case it shows the correct answer. I am not getting whats wrong in my code.
Here is my code in c++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        int l = s.length();
        stack<char> stq;
        int flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++){
            if (s[i] == '(' || s[i] == '{' || s[i] == '[')
                stq.push(s[i]);
            else if (!stq.empty() && s[i] == ')' && stq.top() == '(')
                stq.pop();
            else if (!stq.empty() && s[i] == ']' && stq.top() == '[')
                stq.pop();
            else if (!stq.empty() && s[i] == '}' && stq.top() == '{')
                stq.pop();
            else{
                cout << "not balanced" << endl;
                break;
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0){
            if (stq.empty())
                cout << "balanced" << endl;
            else
                cout << "not balanced" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the link to the problem is https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/parenthesis-checker/0#

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing "not balanced" more than once.

```
Input
2
[][{]
}{
```

```
Output
not balanced
not balanced
not balanced
balanced
```

Why don't you write a function to check for valid parantheses and return true or false? It would be neat and simple that way.

Comment: Thank you i got the problem. I just used break statement before changing the clvalue of flag.